# Portrait mode only-iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an application and designed for only for portrait orientation. However I dont know how to restrict to use only portrait mode, once user upside down or landspace mode, I dont want my screen orinetation changes accordingly.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered here MANY times.  Google is your friend.

Comment: thanks a lot ElJay. I had tried the solution that you have provided, it had messed up once upon a time, now it works perfectly. No problem. sorry for putting easy question here. I attempted to delete, but SO does not allow to delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That can be specified in the App Summary (and also in the rootviewcontroller (whether that be a Nav Controller, TabBar Controller, etc) by overriding this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the app is compiled against the iOS 6 SDK, `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` will never be called. So that part of your answer would be irrelevant. In iOS 6, what the App Summary says (as shown in your screen shot) is gospel (unless filtered by the app delegate or the view controller, but there's no need for that here).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated view of the place where you can make the change in XCode 8.1

[image: Set App Orientation]
Notice that you choose that item (App Summary) on the far left at the top of the project navigator. 
Then, on the right side you need to make sure that General is chosen at the top, then scroll down if needed and you'll see the Device Orientation settings.

[image: xcode 8.1]